# Why all the tables in phpmyadmin cpanel is missing create edit delete and unique id?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have hosted my Laravel project on Shared hosting.
Everything works fine on local but my main problem is in Phpmyadmin when i imported my sql file into it.
In my local i every table has primary key, auto increment and unique id for all the rows in every table. But when i imported sql into cpanel phpmyadmin all the table doesn't have unique id and no option for create edit update and delete.

[image: Image of Cpanel Phpmyadmin]

[image: Image of phpmyadmin in local that i exported to cpanel phpmyadmin]

Comment: There is no relation to PHP here. Use `show create table` to see what the table definition has.

Answer (score 0):

The two problems are related, something has gone wroing in the import process and you don't have a proper primary key defined therefore phpmyadmin won't let you do updates or delete.

How did you export and import the data, please explain step by step so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Add id as primary key and auto increment.Then it will show all options.
Note: Its not php issue.

Comment: I have added it in my local but the problem is while exporting it to the server

Comment: Please properly export data.